# Rapidshare premium download (c#)

Tags: c#, rapidshare

Is there a way to download a file using a rapidshare premium account with c# or java?

Comment: Have you asked on the Rapidshare site?

Comment: if you get it going, can you post the answer up on here. cheers

Comment: maybe it's about time you accept an answer or give some feedback on why the current answers do not suffice for you?

Answer (score 7):

RapidShare has an [API](http://images.rapidshare.com/apidoc.txt) you might want to look into.

Answer (score 2):

There are Web Helpers in C# ( WebClient ) which lets you download content. See an example [here](http://www.csharp-station.com/HowTo/HttpWebFetch.aspx). Now this is the harder way maybe, you might want to see if Rapidshare got an API you can program against, otherwise you need to do the authentication through a webclient, get the image urls and download the images.

Answer (score 1):

yes. The project cryptload (in .net) and jdownloader (in java) do it...

Answer (score 1):

of course. you can do it with any language that sends or receives HTTP with cookies. Is there an easy way? Probably not. You may even need a JS interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

Let's not invent the wheel twice! 
Someone has already created a nice class you can use to download your stuff from rapidshare:

see here : http://sqnco.com/2009/07/simple-rapidshare-download-class-c/

I've just tested it and it works 100%!! There is still some fixing to do on how to display progress of the jobs but the download class itself is very nicely implemented and extremely easy to use!